# $X,Y\sim$ Geo$(p)$, what is $Z=X/(X+Y)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have $X,Y\sim $ Geo$(p)$ with $Z=X/(X+Y)$.  What is the distribution of $Z$?

So the support is $\mathbb{Q}^+\cup \{0\}$

When I try the normal method of

$$f_Z(z)=P(X/(X+Y)=z)$$

I feel like this leads me nowhwere.  I don't know how to split this into a joint case where I can take advantage of the distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we take the definition of Geometric where the support of $X$ and $Y$ is $1, 2, 3, ...$ (number of trials until the first success, not number of failures), then the support of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ is $\{\frac{m}{n}:m,n\in \mathbb N, \gcd(m,n)=1 \text{ and }m<n\}=\mathbb Q\cap(0,1)$

Then

$$f_Z\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=P\left(\frac{X}{X+Y}=\frac{m}{n}\right)=P((n-m)X=mY)$$

But $\gcd(m,n)=1$ implies $\gcd(n-m,m)=1$, so in order to have equality it is necessary and sufficient to have $X=km$ and $y=k(n-m)$ for some integer $k\ge 1$. Thus:

$$f_Z\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=km,Y=k(n-m))=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=km)P(Y=k(n-m))\\
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{km-1}p(1-p)^{k(n-m)-1}=\frac{p^2}{1-p}\frac{(1-p)^n}{1-(1-p)^n}$$